# Interacting with Google Chrome's storage API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, storage

I am relatively new to JavaScript and brand new to Chrome Extension programming and I have been having some trouble interacting with the storage API that can locally store data in your browser. After carefully reading the chrome.storage documentation, I still haven't been able to load anything whatsoever into the storage. Here is the code that I have so far in two parts, the first is my code that defines name and tabs. It calls the second function which is supposed to be interacting with storage:

```js
  var groupmaker = function() {
    var $tabs = document.querySelector("tabs-");
    var $input = document.querySelector("input");
    chrome.tabs.query({windowId: chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT}, function(tabs) {
      setData($input.value, tabs)
      $tabs.innerHTML = `<h1>${$input.value}</h1>`;
      tabs.forEach(tab => {
        $tabs.innerHTML += `
          <a href='${tab.url}'>
            <p>${tab.title}</p>
          </a>
        `;
      });
      $tabs.querySelector('h1').addEventListener('click', toggleHidden);
    });
  };
```

```js
var setData = function(name, tabs){
  chrome.storage.local.set({ name: JSON.stringify(tabs) }, function(){
    // Now data has been saved get ALL data (by passing in null)
    chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(items){
      console.log(items)
    });
  });
}
```

Does anyone see the error in this code? Is there anything special that needs to be set up in the manifest.json file for the extension to work besides the "storage" permission? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please confirm `name` is not null and you're watching background page console.

Comment: name is not null. What do you mean by watching background page console? I actually am not working with a background page. Is that the issue?

Comment: You should watch the console from where you call `console.log`. For example, if you're calling it in background page, you should open background page and see if there're any outputs from its console. As for how to debug background page: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/google-chrome-extension/5938/developer-tool-integration/20829/debugging-the-background-page-script#t=201612080838201839112

Comment: But is it a problem that I don't have a background page altogether? Can you explain a little more about seeing if the background page has any outputs from its console?

Comment: Where did you call this method `setData`?

Comment: My apologies, I made a quick change to the code when trying something. It should and is called in my current code where the "setnget" method is called in the code above from the groupmaker function.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but is "tabs-" a valid selector? Also, as Haibara Ai states, the function is called `setngetData` in one place and `setData` in the other.

Comment: Given the hyphen, you can name selectors to your convenience I believe. Still, my code doesn't work even if I use other selector formats. Additionally, in my current, I am consistent with the naming of that function and it doesn't work with the database.

Comment: You could put `console.log(name);` before `chrome.storage` call and tell us what it outputs, I just suspect it's a valid value.

Comment: And your thought is not correct, `tabs-` doesn't match any css selectors.

Comment: Following your instructions, it console.log(name) outputs the element that I insert into my html input... so just some text string.

Comment: weird, would you mind sharing a simple copy then I can directly debug it?

Comment: Sure! How might I do that? I'm unfamiliar with this site still.

Comment: You can put it in a share site or just put the least code (manifest, background, ....) I can repro directly.

Comment: does codeshare work?

Comment: sure, just shoot me the link

Comment: Here's the link to the codeshare: https://codeshare.io/5OqqPG.

Comment: It works perfectly at my side... so you're watching the logs from popup console, right?

Comment: The log for the name outputs the string typed into the box. The log for the items outputs a crazy object with ASD, groupname, jsonfile, key, name, values.

Comment: Hey, then what's your question?? I mean what do you want to output?

Comment: My goal is to save the data to storage in the applications section when I inspect the extension. I haven't been able to get it to save there in any capacity. My log.console() functions output things but nothing is saving to the browser's local storage. My question and goal is to get it to save to the browser's storage. In the browser's storage, I want the key to be the string the user input, and then the value to be a stringified text that is all of the json arrays for all of the tabs put into a single string.

Comment: See my answer, I believe I have understood what you want.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I understand what you want.

When you call the following line, I guess you want the **value** of `name` to be the key, however, it actually uses the **`"name"`** as the key, that means there will be only one item in your storage, whose key is `"name"`.

```
chrome.storage.local.set({ name: JSON.stringify(tabs) })
```

What you want is to use `[name]`, this is called [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

```
chrome.storage.local.set({ [name]: JSON.stringify(tabs) })
```

Comment: Sorry for being so unclear! Still though, how can I check to be sure that it is saving data to my database? When I checked, there is nothing populating either the local storage or session storage under the application tab of inspect popup.

Comment: Hey, `chrome.storage` is different from Web storage (local storage or session storage). If you want to view what is in `chrome.storage`, the only way is to call `get` method and outputs them; however, if you actually want to use Web storage, you need to directly use them, rather than `chrome.storage`

Comment: great! That makes sense. One final question... upon inspection, it says that the QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM are exceeded which I believe means that the tabs string is too long. Any ideas how I can get around this?

Comment: 1. You could declare [`unlimitedStorage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-local) permission 2. Actually you should simplify your string if not all info is needed, why not just retrieve necessary info from `tabs` and save them?

Comment: Perfect. Ok. And is there a way to view the data that gets saved to my table? I'd like to be able to look and track what is going on there.

Comment: I have mentioned that the only way is to output them. Or if you want, you could install [some helpful extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb), they have done what you want.

Comment: :) Please consider accepting this answer if it helps, that makes me enjoy this community.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. And you may want to edit your question to make it more clear, then anyone else can get help from your question.

Comment: Ok great. I will do that. So I am still having trouble saving things in my memory. When I get all from the chrome.storage.sync.get(null, ...), it isn't getting data from previous entries into the entry bar... So things still aren't saving anywhere. I'm just not sure how to solve this issue.

Comment: That's what I thought, but it doesn't actually save the data. I want it to grab data from previous times that I used chrome.storage.local.set as well as the most recent. It only does it for the most recent so it will only inject the name and the url's of the tabs of the most recent set of tabs. I can't save a set of tabs.

Comment: Have you update as I mentioned? using `[name]` rather than `name`? `chrome.storage.local.set({ [name]: JSON.stringify(tabs) })`?

Comment: Yes. It is actually still losing the old data. Ideally, I want the code to work such that whenever you click the "save tabs" button, it creates a new header with a new set of tabs underneath it. Right now, it is just replaces the old header and set of tabs with a new one. I believe this has to do with it not saving but could be a problem with something else in my code. I should note that I have changed my code a bit as well.